# Macro attached to a button is affecting the columns on the wrong worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

While using the code below it works as written, but only if it is run from the worksheet it is affecting. I am using a button on another worksheet and assigning the macro to it, but then the code affects the sheet I am using the button on. Can anyone help me figure out why this is?

I have inserted a button on Sheet22 in my workbook and the code is intended to sort columns on Sheet8 m(see code below):

```
Sub columnOrder()
Dim search As Range
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim colOrdr As Variant
Dim indx As Integer

colOrdr = Array("Location", "DWH", "CPT Date", "CPT Time", "VRID", "Carrier", "Vehicle ID", "SDT Date", "SDT Time") 'define column order with header names here

cnt = 1

    With Sheet8
    
        For indx = LBound(colOrdr) To UBound(colOrdr)
            Set search = Rows("1:1").Find(colOrdr(indx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not search Is Nothing Then
                If search.Column <> cnt Then
                    search.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Columns(cnt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next indx
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You added a `With` statement, but that's not all you have to do. To make it work, you need to qualify your range objects (like `Rows` and `Columns`) - prefix them with a period (that's what tells it to use `Sheet8`), otherwise it uses `ActiveSheet`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement

Comment: After running this code the first time and seeing the issue, I added the With, End With statement to try and direct the code towards the correct worksheet. With that being said, I am not sure how to qualify the ranges as you suggested. This code is borrowed from an answer to a question that was similar to what I was looking for regarding rearranging columns. Should I set search = Sheet8.Rows("1:1") etc.?

Comment: Change `Rows` to `.Rows` and do the same thing with `Columns`

Comment: So that automatically ties it back to the With Sheet8? Cool.

Comment: Yes, that's how you tell it to use that sheet. It doesn't just automatically know you are trying to use that sheet. Click that link i gave you in the first comment to read about how this works.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I appreciate the explanation.